# Offset as hex from textbox

Tags: c#, offset, nemerle

I'm using `lpBaseAddress          : IntPtr`

but ... I need to enter hex value :-/ like a normal offset

like on VB that could be something like :

```
offset = CLng("&H" + text)
```

So I need to take a value from textbox and make same magic on C# (or Nemerle ^_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to parse hex:

```
string hex = "0a12cc";
long ptr = Convert.ToInt64(hex, 16);
IntPtr newPtr = new IntPtr(ptr);
```

I've used `long` here for illustration, as `IntPtr` could be 32/64.

Comment: what shows ? :S
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte [] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
Pinvoke tells it must be intptr :-S

Answer (score 1):

```
offset = System.Convert.ToInt64(this.yourTextBox.Text, 16);
```

Are you sure you need an Int64 (Long) and not just an Int32 (Int)? If you're a VB6 coder, Int32 (Int) is what you're looking for, not Long.

Comment: @nCdy: My bad, sorry. I just asked because I associate offsets with Ints, and VB6 developers tend to use Longs even within .NET, because they never really look at the new framework.